# Can i pass auto_ptr by reference to functions?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

is the following function OK:

```
void DoSomething(auto_ptr< … >& a)....
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do it but I'm not sure why you would want to do it.

If you're using the auto_ptr to indicate ownership of the ptr (as people generally do), then you only need to pass the auto_ptr to a function if you want to transfer ownership of the ptr to the function, in which case you would pass the auto_ptr by value:

```
void DoSomething(auto_ptr<int> a)
```

So any code calling DoSomething relinquishes ownership of the ptr:

```
auto_ptr<int> p (new int (7));
DoSomething (p);
// p is now empty.
```

Otherwise just pass the ptr by value:

```
void DoSomething(int* a)
{...}

...

auto_ptr<int> p (new int (7));
DoSomething (p.get ());
// p still holds the ptr.
```

or pass a ref to the pointed to object:

```
void DoSomething(int& a)
{...}

...

auto_ptr<int> p (new int (7));
DoSomething (*p);
// p still holds the ptr.
```

The second is usually preferable as it makes it more explicit that DoSomething is unlikely to attempt to delete the object.

Comment: passing the pointer by value is not safe - memory leaks could occur.
creating the object without 'new' means that the object will be on the stack - not sure it is the best approach either.

Comment: @eriks: Memory leaks *can* occur in many situations; even if you pass an `auto_ptr` by reference, someone could call `delete ptr.get()` which would be worse. Passing pointers by value passes no information about transfer of ownership or the correct form of deletion so - in the absence of documentation to the contrary - I wouldn't expect the callee to delete the object pointed to.

Comment: @eriks: You won't get memory leak, you'll just get dangling pointers.

Comment: @eriks: I've expanded my examples to hopefully clarify.